# My dropdown menu is only showing one item

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I tried creating a dropdown menu using HTML and CSS but although the dropdown display works, its only showing one of the 4 items i listed. I've tried rearranging both the HTML and the CSS to no avail. The only time i'm able to see more than one item is when the font size of the dropdown content is .5 . HTML and CSS code is below.

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;}

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    min-width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;}

    .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;}

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #329A55;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="logos/NewsHubLogo.png" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="">Global</a></li>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#">North America</a>
                            <a href="#">South America</a>
                            <a href="#">Asia</a>
                            <a href="#">Europe</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <li><a href="">Economy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Africa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Hot Topics</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img src="logos/globelogo.png" class="menu-icon">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` can't have a `<div>` as a child

Comment: The behaviour you describe does *not*  happen with the code you posted, so it's impossible to help you.

Comment: as @Johannes has stated .. You need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  --  If it works for us, and we can't reproduce your problem, there is no solution to be offered.